# Webview doesn't show the latest webpage

Tags: android, webview

I have been working with Android webview for a month or so. However, i have noticed that a number of times (not always) when i update the concerned html webpage, the webview just shows the old webpage. Even after i close the app and run again the problem still remains.

I have tried to use `myWebview.reload()` in `onCreate()` and `onResume()` method but most of the time i have to build my app from the whole on my device to get the latest webpage which is very time consuming. Any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can "disable" the WebView's cache to make sure you always get a fresh page:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     view.clearCache(true);
}
```

But be aware that this will in practice disable the cache. If you own the server, you better fix the server's headers handling.